# Syntastic not checking python code

Tags: vim, python-mode, syntastic

I have both syntastic and python-mode installed.. However, I want to syntax check using syntastic.. To do this, I have disabled pymode check with, `let g:pymode_lint = 0`

Also, when python file if opened, syntastic says that checker is present, but does not detect errors..

Currently active checker = python

Comment: To modify my question, I want to check my code using default python checker...

Comment: Syntastic's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).

Comment: Syntastic require the syntax checker apart from itselfs. Did you installed checker (like `flake8`) in `$PATH`?